# Searching through table entries by column order based on lookup table

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Contrary to what someone has voted, I have researched this, but I am only 9 and am trying to learn how to do a search across columns in a table.  I want to build a simple website for my school that lets the year R children select two sounds from a list of phonics and then it searches for the top three or five words that contain those phonic sounds.  I have built a table that has over 500 words in it (and I will keep adding to the words over time).  I have listed the phonics of every word in the table in columns to the right of each word (there are up to 12 phonic columns so far) and I have a table of all the phonics used in alphabetical order.  The website needs to have a page that has two selection boxes that allows the user to select from my list of phonics (I can do this part).  Then the first phonic searches through my table of words searching for matches in the first column of the phonics of each word.  For all words where there is a match the second phonic is then searched in columns 2 then 3 and so on to see if 3 or more matches can be found.  If there are more than 5 matches the matches are selected at random up to 5 matches and returned on the results screen.  Can anyone help.  I have worked hard on this and my teacher says it is too advanced for her, but I think it should be possible - I can do it in Excel - I filter and for the first phonic I select that phonic in the first phonics column, then for phonic 2 I filter it in the second phonics column (and so on - if there is no match in 2 then I deselect column 2 filter and then filter on column 3).  Can I build a hidden HTML table and do this in HTML or JavaScript or similar?  I am learning JavaScript, but have only learnt a little so far. I am in year 5.

Comment: Your phonics should be held in JavaScript. What type of structure you use (arrays or an array of objects) will determine how you access/filter your information. It is a bit difficult to determine what you actually need without seeing some data.

Comment: Hello Jeff and thank you.  I currently have everything in Excel but I can create an HTML table if that is needed.  I have: column 1 = Words. C2 = Phonic 1. C3=P2, C4=P3 etc up to Phonic 12.  In another table I have a list of 42 phonics in alphabetical order.  So I want the year R child to just pick two phonics from my list and then match Phonic 1 against all matching phonics in Column 2 (C2 = P1 for the Word in C1).  If there are more than 5 matches, then Phonic 2 is matched against all Phonics in Column 3 (C3 = P2 for the Word in C1). If less than 5 then search P2 agains C3, then C4, etc.

Comment: Here is an example

Comment: Tiger | t | igh | g | er | Word in C1, Phonics in C2 to C5.  If child selects T and G then these would match a search of T in C2 and G in C4.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the delay in answering - down with the flu.
First off you need to work out some sort of data structure to be held in JavaScript (forget about HTML tables as they will only hinder you).
I would use something like:

```
var Phonics = {
   "tiger"    : "| t | ig | g | er |",
   "elephant" : "| e | ......"
};
```

Here you are using a JavaScript Object followed by a string value. To return the possible values you would use `var value = Phonic['tiger']` then use string search to apply your 'filters'. Another concern is the conflict, that may arise, when 2 or more objects have similar values.

Hope this puts you on the right track.